# Two entity have each other

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

In this case, the store can have many owners, and the owners can have many store.

However, when i save the entity by using Repository and the problem happen:

**Maximum call stack size exceeded**

I think it need to use Nested Tree annotation? But i dont know how to correct it. Please help!

```
@Entity('store')
export class StoreEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  ...
  @ManyToMany(type => UserEntity, user => user.ownStores)
  @JoinTable()
  owners: UserEntity[];
}
```

```
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  email: string;

  ...

  @ManyToMany(type => StoreEntity, store => store.owners)
  ownStores: StoreEntity[];
```